# How to resolve JavaScript appendChild problem when new message receive

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, ejs

I need some help how to fixed this JavaScript appendChild everything I receive new message it will append the old message, all I want is the new message will show. please have a look into my code.

```
socket.on('receiveNewMessage', (data) => {
    newMessages.push(data);
    // console.log('I recived your message: ', newMessages);
    // newMsg.innerHTML = '';
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.classList.add('msgNewMesagesData');
    li.setAttribute('id', 'msgNewMesagesData');
    li.innerHTML = `
            <button id="openCHat" data-socketId="" data-userId="" data-userName="}" data-img="" data-email="" class="msg"  title="chat with ">
                <div class="msg-profile group">
                    <img id="img" src="${data.img}" alt="${data.username}">
                </div> 
                <div class="msg-detail">
                    <div class="msg-username">${data.username}</div>
                        <div class="userDetails">                     
                            <span class="msg-message">${data.messages}</span>                                                                   
                        </div>
                </div>
            </button>`;
    newMsg.appendChild(li);
    newMsg.insertBefore(li, newMsg.childNodes[0]);
    playSound();
});
```

Thanks you and advance
best regards,
ELmer

[JavaScript appendChild](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejbSX.png)

Comment: Please add `newMsg` code, it's unclear what it's supposed to be. According to some of your code it should be a `ul` and then the next line contradicts that

Comment: Yeah but if other user will send new message it will remove that user message. I just link LinkedIn messing.